# CSS calculate using initial value

Tags: css, visual-studio

is there a way in CSS to get the initial parameter of something, without using javascript, for example:

```
width: calc(initial-20px);
```

if so, ho can i retrieve the value of specific parameters, like **width.initial**?

**SCENARIO**

It's a visual studio web browser, (it doesn't support css3 by default), i whant an element to look like highlited, but i can only do it through html attributes(i wanna go the easy way). So i could just `style="background-color: yellow !important;"`, but what if background is already yellow? So i decided that calculating the highlight color would fix be awesome ( as i know now it is impossible through css ) `background-color:  rgb(initial,calc(initial-50),initial) !important;` something like that. So this is a scenario. Suggestions are apreciated.

Comment: If you show us a bit more detailed use case of what you're trying to achieve, we may be able to provide a more appropriate answer.

Comment: @Fabrício Matté im doing a hackaround in C# to highlight visual studio browser elements, and im not sure if javascript will do there

Comment: i could just assign a background color, but this color might not differ from the ones loaded on html, so i whated to calculate the color dynamically

Comment: Calculating the color dynamically is a bit hard without JavaScript. There is -webkit-filter but it is, of course, blink/webkit specific and applies to the whole element.

Comment: yea, but this browser can't even support css3 by default

Comment: Yeah, thought so. Sorry, I'm a bit lost here, do you want to change the width and/or background? It'd be nice if you could reproduce a similar scenario with html so that we can hack away, or at least post some screenshots of how it looks and how you'd like it to look.

Comment: Maybe tag the question with visual studio? Someone who has experience with what you're trying to achieve may see the question then.

Comment: @Fabrício Matté see my update

Comment: Why would you require CSS3 but not want to use javascript?  Any browser that has CSS3 support will have javascript support as well..  Seems like an odd limitation to put on yourself.

Comment: it's not, but javascript won't help here either i think. Thats why im'd downloading chromnium for visual studio right now

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, no it is not possible to do this with css. You also can't perform calculations like that. You can only do calculations for percentages, like Mooseman said (edit: Mooseman deleted his answer. It mentioned that you can use `width: calc(100% - 40px);` for example, but you can't use `initial` like that). for either of those things you would need to use JavaScript.

Edit: Another option for modifying width could be a `margin`, although that doesn't necessarily do exactly what you want. For highlighting, you could use something like this:

```css
p {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}
p:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4));
}
```

```html
<p>Example paragraph with background</p>
```

This way you overlay a translucent white layer on top of your `background-color`, making it a bit lighter. That way you can change the background colour without having to know what the original background was.

Comment: i thought so, sad though

Answer (score 1):

i think you can Use LESS.

You Can See Here:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/wa-less/index.html

Comment: LESS looks cool, but doesn't give my solution, as it requires javascript